# extract data from textfile

Tags: python, extract

I need to extract the (specific: `Lot`, `Long`, `name`, `type`) data from text file (.txt) and create a convex hull from extracted data.  As far as I've known, the extracted data should be in float format, not string.

text file is kinda like this (with a lot more data):

```
location_type, parent_station, stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id
0,,10000,10000,"Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd","",-32.14796,116.020217222222,4
0,,10001,10001,"Albany Hwy After Frys L","",-32.144985,116.018336666667,3
0,,10002,10002,"Albany Hwy After Clarence Rd","",-32.1420722222222,116.017182777778,3
0,,10003,10003,"Albany Hwy After Rogers L","",-32.1391138888889,116.017382222222,3
0,,10004,10004,"Albany Hwy After Galliers Av","",-32.1365533333333,116.017569444444,3
0,,10005,10005,"Albany Hwy Armadale Kelmscott Hospital","Armadale Kelmscott Hospital",-32.1348155555556,116.017707222222,3
0,,10006,10006,"Albany Hwy After Lilian Av","",-32.1304322222222,116.018038333333,3
```

But till now I (been try and error since morning) only manage to extract the whole data, not the specific ones.

```
 try:
    fp = open(filename)
    myList = []
    next(fp)
    for f in fp:
        myList.append(list(f.strip().split(",")))

    fp.close()

    return myList
```

need help to crack this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Use the ``csv`` module. YOur data looks like it's Comma Value Separated.

Comment: This may well have been covered elsewhere but I don't think that the suggested duplicate is a very good one. It is certainly not a good canonical question about best practices for reading in a CSV file using python, as it mainly deals with a specific feature of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from the `csv` module:

```
import csv
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
with open('filename') as file:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024)) # determine the file format
    file.seek(0)                                   # rewind back to start of file
    dialect.skipinitialspace = True                # skip whitespace after delimiter
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(file, dialect=dialect)
    for row in dict_reader:
        pp.pprint(row)
```

This will print out each row of your .csv file as a dictionary. I am using [`pprint.PrettyPrinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html?highlight=prettyprint#pprint.PrettyPrinter) to print out the dictionary in a neater way.

The [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object creates keys based on the names on your first row for you automatically. The `skipinitialspace` option to `dialect` ensures that these names don't contain any blank space at the start.

Output from the first iteration of the code above:

```
{'location_type': '0',
 'parent_station': '',
 'stop_code': '10000',
 'stop_desc': '',
 'stop_id': '10000',
 'stop_lat': '-32.14796',
 'stop_lon': '116.020217222222',
 'stop_name': 'Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd',
 'zone_id': '4'}
```

The [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) contains `key: value` pairs, so to get a specific value you refer to it by its key. For example, to get the `stop_name` for a given `row`, you would do `name = row['stop_name']`. If you wanted to print the coordinates, name and type from each row of your file, you could change the `for` loop above to something like this:

```
for row in dict_reader:
    lat = row['stop_lat']
    lon = row['stop_lon']
    name = row['stop_name']
    type = row['location_type']
    print '({},{}): {}, {}'.format(lat, lon, name, type)
```

You can look up `str.format` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). It's basically a nicer way to build up a string containing variables.

Output:

```
(-32.14796,116.020217222222): Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd, 0
(-32.144985,116.018336666667): Albany Hwy After Frys L, 0
(-32.1420722222222,116.017182777778): Albany Hwy After Clarence Rd, 0
(-32.1391138888889,116.017382222222): Albany Hwy After Rogers L, 0
(-32.1365533333333,116.017569444444): Albany Hwy After Galliers Av, 0
(-32.1348155555556,116.017707222222): Albany Hwy Armadale Kelmscott Hospital, 0
(-32.1304322222222,116.018038333333): Albany Hwy After Lilian Av, 0
```

---

#### edit

If for example you wanted to get a list of all the latitudes and longitudes as floats, you could do:

```
import csv
with open('filename') as file:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024)) # determine the file format
    file.seek(0)                                   # rewind back to start of file
    dialect.skipinitialspace = True                # skip whitespace after delimiter
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(file, dialect=dialect)
    lats = []
    lons = []
    for row in dict_reader:
        lats.append(float(row['stop_lat']))
        lons.append(float(row['stop_lon']))
```

Comment: Thanks, but my data comes with .txt format. It means that I need to convert to .csv first. Is it okay if I am going to use the data for convex hull and kd-trees after that.

Comment: @user3664111 `.csv` or `.txt` are just file extensions, you don't have to convert between them. I tested this solution on your data and it works, regardless of the extension. I think this is the best way to solve your problem as it makes use of built-in python modules rather than reinventing the wheel. By the way, don't forget to upvote answers you find useful and accept your favourite answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Fenech. It works now, but then how do I extract only coordinates, name and type from dict. Not to forget, I am a newbie in both programming and python.

Comment: @user3664111 Of course, it depends on how you want to use them. I've edited my question to show how you could print them out. If you want to do something different, you'd have to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I might be asking a wrong question. Actually, what I wanna do is, extract the data from file and process it (not yet to print). The coordinates will be wrapped using convex hull and get the ranges between max and min using kd-ranges search. 

When I try to get the coordinates into convex hull, it results into error as dict_reader has no __getitem__ object? How to fix this?

Comment: @user3664111 Are you talking about using [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy-spatial-convexhull)? You really should edit the question and title so that it is clear exactly what you want to do with each row.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. My apologize.

Comment: @user3664111 it's still not clear in the question exactly what format you would like the data to be in. If you explain exactly what you want, I'll be able to change my answer.

Comment: I think it should be in .float format. Not string because, I'll not be able to use the extracted data if it's in .str format.

Comment: @user3664111 please see my latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.coderholic.com/parsing-csv-data-in-python/
Take a look at that link, it shows you how to handle a CSV in python.

This code from the link above:

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('data.csv'))
# Read the column names from the first line of the file
fields = data.next()
for row in data:
        # Zip together the field names and values
    items = zip(fields, row)
    item = {}
        # Add the value to our dictionary
    for (name, value) in items:
        item[name] = value.strip()
```

Puts the data into a dictionary and then you can get the values you want by name, instead of having to remember where in the list the data has gone

It will essentially look like this (example):

```
{"id": "0", "name": "name", "date": "2009-01-01"},
{"id": "1", "name": "another name", "date": "2009-02-01"}
```

In your case:

```
{"location_type": 0, "parent_station": "", "stop_id": 10000, "stop_code": 10000, "stop_name": "Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd", "stop_desc": "", "stop_lat": -32.14796, "stop_lon": 116.020217222222, "zone_id": 4}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not encouraged as they do not provide a self-contained solution to the problem. Perhaps you could provide an example in your answer?

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth applying it to this question rather than just copying it straight off the site?

Comment: Considering there is a lot of data per column in the file that is being provided, I decided to use the dictionary example from the website to improve its readability, and assumed that most would be able to understand the jist of the dictionary's purpose. Otherwise it would be difficult to see the entire dictionary. 
However, as you mention it, I shall add it in.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it without importing a specific lib :

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (location_type, parent_station, stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id) = line.split(",")
        d[stop_id] = (location_type, parent_station, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id)
print d
```

It's more pythonic !

Comment: Thanks, and I have tried it but there is error. Too many values to unpack.

Comment: I did it with your test file and had immediate results. Check your data, there is probably somewhere one line with an extra value.

Comment: Still not working. Have checked it and it all same.

Comment: There is nothing "more pythonic" about writing your own, highly inflexible solution. Modules like `csv` are part of the python core for a good reason!